# Sharepoint API update a file throws Specified value is not supported for the serverRelativeUrl parameter

Tags: sharepoint-online, api, update, postman

I am trying to update a file in sharepoint using API. I am trying in POSTMAN only.
Below are the url and headers which i send. I am using PUT Method.
url:

```
https://groupname.sharepoint.com/sites/MMSN/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('Shared Documents/DB_Folder')/Files('db_sample.json')/$value

Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSU
X-HTTP-Method: PUT
```

Error:

```
<m:error 
    xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <m:code>-2147024809, System.ArgumentException</m:code>
    <m:message xml:lang="en-US">serverRelativeUrl&#xD;
Parameter name: Specified value is not supported for the serverRelativeUrl parameter.</m:message>
</m:error>
```

Is my relative url and headers are valid ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter of GetFileByServerRelativeUrl method should be the **server-relative URL for the file**. While you set a folder path.

Reference:

- [Working with files by using REST](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest#working-with-files-by-using-rest)
- [How to update the Content?](https://collab365.community/tutorial-create-read-update-delete-files-sharepoint-using-rest/)
- [How to Upload File in Document Library in SharePoint Using REST API](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/91b369/how-to-upload-file-in-document-library-in-sharepoint-using-r/)

Comment: Thank You @baker_kong_MSFT